# Cookie doesn't always get set after a redirect

Tags: http, redirect, cookies

We have the following flow for lost-password:

1. User gets a link via email.
2. User clicks link with a unique token. A session cookie gets set
3. User get immediately redirected to a lost-password form

We've noticed that when the browser opens the third step, it's missing the cookie we just set.

The interesting thing here is that this *only* happens when a user clicks the link from for example a gmail web interface. If the user manually copy-pasted the link and put it in their address bar, the cookie does get set.

I'm wonder if others have ran into this. Maybe it's some advanced privacy protection browsers have that I haven't seen before.